# All delivered Scheduled Notifications are cleared from Notification Center when one is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I scheduled multiple Local Notification for the user. All of them are also delivered on their specified time. However, when I try to open any one of them from Notification Center, all of them are getting cleared.

In a rightful scenario, I don't want all them to be cleared from notification centre, only those which are tapped to be opened.

Also, i tried commenting below code from AppDelegate.m, but the issue still persists.  `[[UIApplicationsharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];`

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue here due to which my scheduled notifications are cleared from Notification Center even when I'm tapping to open only one of them?

Below is the code I'm using to schedule Local Notifications -

```
NSDateComponents *components = [SSUtility hoursMinuteAndSectionsForDate:date];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];

    NSLog(@"Hour %ld Min %ld ", hour,minute);

    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];

    /* Set notification */

    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
    content.body = body;
    // content.categoryIdentifier=NSNotificationC;
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    content.userInfo = userInfo;
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                          content:content
                                                                          trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            SSLOG(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: did you found a solution ? i had the same issue

Comment: It turns out that this is the default behaviour when you use UNUserNotificationCenter instead of deprecated UILocalnotification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did't believe that this is a default behaviour so what i found:

- if you use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` then all delivered reminders are deleted on tap
- if you use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` then delivered reminders remain on the notification center

so try to use the `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` instead of `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [fireDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Add some text to `content.body` solve the problem:

```
content.body = 'Any text'
```